# How long normally does it take for app update to go live in Google Play Console closed testing?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Just created a custom track in Closed testing in Google Play Console. First app submission took 2 days which was pretty quick considering the potential delays mentioned in the home page. However I found that subsequent app update seems to take a long time as well.

Submitted an update 10 hours ago but it is still 'Being reviewed'. So far I found that the app updates only gets approved around noon time in US time zone so probably a human reviewer is involved and not automated. Is there a way to increase to speed of app updates for closed testing? Not sure if its because I am using a custom track?

There's an iOS app as well, submitted for closed testing using TestFlight, but app updates on the same version (just different build number) gets live almost instantly (less than 15 minutes) so I am not sure if I'm not doing something obvious on Android side. Seems like there's no way for me to release a new build on Google Play Console without creating a New Release - and a new release always gets stuck in 'being reviewed' for a long time.

Comment: For faster updates use instead "Internal Testing" track

Comment: +1 to [internal testing track](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB), this skips the review altogether. You can also use [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en-GB), depending who you're sending this to.

Comment: Cool that's good to know! The reason we chose closed testing because we are letting a small outside group of people testing the app, we don't have the list of all their emails so we just share the app link to them and they can download themselves. Guess there's no run away from the update process for this case.